# AndroidAnnotations - Create Singleton EBean without adding the dependency

Tags: android-annotations, greenrobot-eventbus

I am using [androidannotations](http://androidannotations.org/) in an Android project and I have an EBean defined as:

```
@EBean(scope = Singleton)
class MyBean {
    public void someFunction() {
    }
}
```

This bean is created whenever it is first required, that is, whenever I have:

```
@Bean
MyBean myBean;
```

in some class. 
I am also using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) in this project, and a function in `MyBean` is a `@Subscriber`. This function is not called (when an `Event` is posted) because an instance of `MyBean` does not exist (since I don't have the dependency anywhere). How can I create an instance of `MyBean` without specifically adding the dependency anywhere?

My temporary solution is to simply define the bean in my Application class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, you can't create an `EBean` without injecting it somewhere. Refer this issue: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1692

My solution is to have a class `EBeanManager` (which is also an `EBean`) which simply injects the beans I need created. `EBeanManager` is injected into my `Application` class. The reason I'm doing it in a separate class is to avoid clutter in my `Application` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it the cleanest way possible.  Have your CustomApplication class include @Bean MyBean myBean, even if it never calls a function on it.  With AA and event bus subscriber classes, this is the only solution I have found.

The class needs to be instantiated somewhere.  Since it's a singleton, it seems cleanest to do it in the CustomApplication class.  An alternative might be to make the class a Service (in the Android sense - "extends Service"), which would let you declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml file.  But since you don't require any Android service functionality, this seems like the wrong way to go about it.